# Making a test fail if an HTTP request fails in Cypress

Tags: cypress

I'm testing an app with Cypress, and the tests go against real HTTP servers. I'm not stubbing the HTTP requests.

Is there a way to make my tests fail if any of the HTTP requests fail?

There is a solution that seems ok in [this other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61362670/cypress-let-test-fail-if-console-error-occurs), but I wonder if there is a more proper solution. In my case, I'm not always converting all HTTP errors into invocations to `console.error`.

Comment: I know you probably have a good reason for it, but have you thought about using something like https://mswjs.io/ instead of a real endpoint?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can listen to the request using cy.intercept() & check the status code etc.

Ref : https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept.html#Intercepting-a-response

Example 1 :

```
// Wait for intercepted HTTP request
cy.intercept('POST', '/users').as('createUser')
// ...
cy.wait('@createUser')
  .then(({ request, response }) => {
    expect(response.statusCode).to.eq(200)
  })
```

Example 2 :

```
   // Listen to GET to comments/1
    cy.intercept('GET', '**/comments/*').as('getComment')

    // we have code that gets a comment when
    // the button is clicked in scripts.js
    cy.get('.network-btn').click()

    // https://on.cypress.io/wait
    cy.wait('@getComment').its('response.statusCode').should('be.oneOf', [200, 304])
```

Comment: Thanks! this works perfectly for me, I could intercept a url of `*` and ensure the code is between 200 and 399. Thanks.